# Network settings on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless, ethernet

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS as a VM with the bridged mode. The host is Windows.
I set these configurations to their right values:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.1.16.66
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 10.1.16.255
    dns - nameserver 8.8.8.8
    gateway 10.1.16.254
```

I also did the right settings for `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/hosts` files

I run `ping 8.8.8.8` but it fails. However, my host machine uses only Wifi. Must I rename eth0 to wlan0 ? If yes, then why when I run `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` it displays me : `"wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device" ?`
Note: The same settings work on my other PC connected to Internet using cable.
Host settings (Windows 7):

```
IP address: 10.1.16.67
DNS Nameserver: 8.8.8.8
Netmask 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 10.1.16.254
```

VM settings (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, on a VirtualBox -last version)

Comment: No eth0 is right. Whats the output of the ping? Can you reach your gateway with ping?

Comment: I pinged my gateway and it says it is unreachable

Comment: Please follow the steps in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/353047/no-wlan0-interface-after-uninstall-ubuntu-13-04/353053#353053)

Comment: Yes, I followed them before I asked this question but I do not find the module to run (i can not guess which one it is, which line displays it)

Comment: But everything is fine from your Hostsystem? Are you 100% sure the settings are correct and the IP you assigned isn't already taken? Can you post the output of `ifconfig eth0`.

Comment: @Pabi On my host system i connect perfectly well to internet. Do you think if the IP is taken it would display me such an error ? (Someone uses it on his laptop, but i am not sure his laptop is running now). I just tried to ping that address from the host machine and it is unreachable, so it is free to use

Comment: Yes if the IP you give the machine is taken it would produce an error like this. Is there a DHCP in your network you can try to use? I really think it is something wrong with your network settings.

Comment: I am using a static address in a private network. I did the same settings on an other PC connect by a CABLE and my VM works (exactly  the same host, only internet connection is different: wifi vs cable)

Comment: @begueradj, Could you add detailed/complete configuration you are using?

Comment: The settings are coorect, it is jsut because my VM does not detect the wifi card adapter (aparently). This is my wifi card: `atheros ar9285 802.11b/g/n wifi adapter`

Comment: @begueradj No, VM guest does't not see Host network interfaces. Just confirm VM Guest setting > network > As `Bridged` and choose your host network interface `wlan0` probably

Comment: @Sneetsher Yes, I did that, but once in the VM i can not connect to internet

Comment: Must I use a USB wifi key instead ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to rename the interface, it must be `eth0` on the guest. As Sneetsher explained, the VM does not have direct access to the host's NIC.

From the [VirtualBox Documentation (Chapter 6)](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged):

> **Note**
>
> Bridging to a wireless interface is done differently from bridging to a wired interface, because most wireless adapters do not support promiscuous mode. All traffic has to use the MAC address of the host's wireless adapter, and therefore VirtualBox needs to replace the source MAC address in the Ethernet header of an outgoing packet to make sure the reply will be sent to the host interface. When VirtualBox sees an incoming packet with a destination IP address that belongs to one of the virtual machine adapters it replaces the destination MAC address in the Ethernet header with the VM adapter's MAC address and passes it on. VirtualBox examines ARP and DHCP packets in order to learn the IP addresses of virtual machines.

Since you use static IP addressing, VirtualBox can't learn from DHCP packets (please post host, VM and gateway addresses, it could be a trivial error).

Please use DHCP instead so VirtualBox can learn the guest address.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: I will reinstall a new VM and do what you said. Thank you.

Comment: I edited my question to display the settings you asked me (both the host and the guest)

Comment: Double-check your gateway setting in the VM: gateway 10.1.16.255, hope it is a typo :P (if it isn't, you are using the broadcast address as the gateway)

Comment: Thank you for correcting me, it was just an error in writing it. I corrected it now

Comment: I reinstalled a new VM. I wrote only `auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp`, when I run `ping 8.8.8.8` it says Destination net unreachable (same problem as before)

Comment: Can you ping the host machine from the VM?

Comment: No, I can not ping the host from the guest (I think it is a normal thing since I used Briged Networking option)

Comment: On this [link](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#nichardware)  it says that Virtualbox can virtualize the following six types of networking hardware). How can I know which networking hardware type do I have ?

Comment: This list selects which adapter is virtualized and presented to your VM, not the one you have in your host. The default should work (it is the most supported one), and the last one (virtio-net) is a "special" way of presenting hardware to virtual machines.

Comment: I've just tried bridged networking in Windows host but I'm sorry I couldn't reproduce your error. Does your VM work in NAT mode (no "NAT network", just NAT) or is it absolutely broken?

Comment: You succeeded to connect to Internet from your VM with the briged networking mode only ? You did not insert a USB wifi key to your VM instead ?

Comment: Yes, bridged networking (wifi adapter), live [DSL](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org) (got the IP from DHCP server) and Win7 host. But I am unable to see traffic to/from the VM with [Wireshark](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org) on the host machine, which really puzzles me because traffic is flowing thorugh the interface but Wireshark is not showing it.

Comment: Did you use a USB wifi key for the VM ? And really without NAT ? It is NORMAL you can not capture the traffic between your host and guest using WireShark: to do that you must use host only networking option instead of bridged networking (I am sure of this, I experienced it several times)

Comment: No USB adapter, just the laptop one (Intel Centrino Wireless-N) in bridged mode. I disabled Host-Only adapter because I was not going to use it, I don't know if it makes any difference. Are you using USB adapter? By the way (maybe off-topic to the main question, sorry), I am able to capture traffic with Wireshark with Linux as host in bridged mode (ethernet interface, not tested with WiFi right now), it might be how WinPcap works or something about Windows networking internals.

Comment: I am not using a USB adapter. But it is flabbergasting that you do not use NAT or a USB wifi key (adpater). I looked the whole Internet and i did not find anyone who use bridge networking mode without a USB adapter.

Comment: I realize that wireless bridges can be troublesome ([not only](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/clientmode#bridged.client.mode.issues) with virtual machines), but for basic scenarios it works fine. The only reason (for me) to use a USB wireless adapter was when I really needed the _wireless_ part and not only the _connectivity_. For example using [BackTrack](http://www.backtrack-linux.org) in VM or other wireless-oriented distributions.