# problem with aircrack-ng

Tags: aircrack-ng

wehen i run this commend sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
I get this error:[image] wlan0      Unknown     wl - [phy0]mon0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

Comment: You might want to check this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/353047/no-wlan0-interface-after-uninstall-ubuntu-13-04

Comment: did you down your wlan0 interface ? `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down` and did you kill those PIDs that is said you needed to kill  `sudo kill 561` `sudo kill 563` `sudo kill 811` `sudo kill 6116`

Comment: yes I did . I steel get the error and more PID to kill

Answer (score 0):

After you put your device 'wlan0' into monitor mode, it most likely shows up as 'mon0'.

check this by doing: `ifconfig` after you put it into the monitor-mode. You should see something other than before.

check out [Aircrack-ng, using airmon-ng to change to monitor mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549026/aircrack-ng-using-airmon-ng-to-change-to-monitor-mode/648826#648826) for understanding what airmon-ng does.

so: 'wlan0' is not found, because it is no more a active device, since you put it into monitor-mode. just use 'mon0' instead.